# What do I put in "INSTALLED_APPS" for django-simple-ratings?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to install django-simple-ratings.

It requires django-generic-aggregation. However, neither set of docs mentions anything about adding a line to INSTALLED_APPS.

So going through the instructions works fine until I put `from rating.models import Ratings` in one of my models. I get the error

```
No module named rating.models
```

My first assumption is that indeed I need to put something in INSTALLED_APPS for django to load the django-simple-ratings module. But what is that string? I've tried `django-simple-ratings` and `djangosimpleratings` but neither works. Do I need to do this for django-generic-aggregation as well?

Perhaps a better question is: for any given Django module, how does one find the string required to install it in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: `rating.models` should mean either there is a module (the folder rating) is within the django project, or it's installed as a python app within that python environment. the `INSTALL_APPS` isn't for django to learn about the existence of your module. It's used for two things: autodiscover  (when you run manage.py syncdb) and for django internal functionality such as `reverse`

Comment: Yes, I'm running syncdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here it is. First, the name of the app in INSTALLED_APPS  is just `ratings`. Second, isn't it `from ratings.models import Ratings`. This worked for me.

Comment: That's it. So I don't need to do anything for django-generic-aggregation?

Comment: I don't have an idea. Never used either. I only downloaded it and added it to one of my projects to see where the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when an app's name contains dashes, it is written with underscores in INSTALLED_APPS. In your case that would be django_simple_ratings.

Also, you missed the 't' in ratings here in your post. Have you written it like this in the code as well?

Comment: D'oh! No, just in this post :)

Comment: Keep it with underscores. Are you using virtual environment? Have you installed the app at the right place?

Comment: I'm not using a virtualenv. I just did pip install django-simple-ratings